# How to use ng-bootstrap with AngularJS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bootstrap

does anyone use NG-Bootstrap (Angular directives specific to Bootstrap 4) with AngularJs (NOT Angular 2)? Im using JAvascript and not TypeScript so I cant imagen how the Installation works. Also im using Bower and Grunt if it matters for anyone.

I hope Someone could help me with this, bec. i rly. like to use ng-bootstrap and bootstrap 4.o

Answer (score 2):

NG Bootstrap requires Angular 2. This is directly from their [Getting Started guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started):

> This repository contains a set of native Angular directives based on
>   Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or
>   Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only required dependencies
>   are:
>
> - Angular (***requires* Angular version 2 or higher**, tested with 2.0.0)
> - Bootstrap CSS (tested with 4.0.0-alpha.6)

If you are using Angular 1.x you could instead use [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but that only works for Bootstrap 3. I don't know whether you'll find a library of Angular 1.x directives for Bootstrap 4 (yet).